# Is there a Midlet emulator that emulates custom screen sizes, reading from flash card, web access, camera and bluetooth?

Tags: emulator, jar

I have a lot of Midlets (Java apps, *.jar, for mobile phones) and I would like to test in my computer before using on my mobile.

There are some programs (like MidpX) that can emulate some of them, but I have a lot with different screen sizes and some use web access, camera and bluetooth and read some data from flash card - they normally cannot be emulated in MidpX.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility is [MicroEmulator](http://www.microemu.org/) :

> This is Java 2 Micro Edition (J2ME)
>   CLDC/MIDP Emulator. Allows demonstrate
>   MIDlet based applications in web
>   browser applet, also can be run as
>   standalone java application.
>
> MicroEmulator is a pure Java
>   implementation of Java ME in Java SE.
>   MicroEmulator is licensed under LGPL
>   so it is possible to link and
>   distribute commercial software with
>   its libraries.

Some more projects are :

[App Runner](http://www.netmite.com/android/) - Run Any Java/J2ME/MIDP NATIVELY

[Kemulator](http://kemulator.sourceforge.net/) - KDE emulator frontend written in C++ using the QT/KDE toolkit.

[Kwyshell Midp2EXE Free J2ME/MIDP Jar File Emulator](http://www.mydailysoftwares.com/2010/02/702/kwyshell-midp2exe-free-j2memidp-jar-file-emulator/) - converts MIDP application to Win32 PE format, to be run on Windows.

[Mpowerplayer](http://thinkabdul.com/2007/11/25/mpowerplayer-free-midp-20-emulator-to-preview-test-java-j2me-jarjad-mobile-games-applications-software-on-computer/) - freeware desktop based MIDP 2.0 emulator for computers that allows preview, play and test JAR/JAD based Java J2ME mobile games and applications on the desktop PC in a virtualized environment with full internet access from the host’s network connection, available [here](http://webstart.mpowerplayer.com/).

[Android J2ME Runner](http://androidcommunity.com/forums/f12/j2me-midlet-app-runner-emulator-out-6129/) for Android 1.0, G1 or Emulator.

<sup>(not having the right development environment, I can't verify that this fulfills all your needs)</sup>

Comment: I thought it is designed only to show Midlet apps on a browser, like OperaMini simulator (http://www.opera.com/mobile/demo/), but I saw that you can create a JNLP, installing the applet in your computer. Ok for internet access, but I don't know how to put it to function. Well, we can choose six different screen sizes. I don't know if there is support to simulate camera, bluetooth and flash card... +1 for mentioning and giving some hope...

Comment: I have added some more, but it is just google-work for "MIDP Emulator". Apparently there are heaps of those, but I can't tell which one is the best for you (or for anybody else...).

Comment: I use Kwyshell Midp2EXE. Is is nice but does not have what I want. I'll try other solutions...

Comment: App Runner: for Android (or with Android emulator); Kemulator: for Linux (does it function for Midlets?); Mpowerplayer: the best until now (an warning screen is so boring for touch games, no bluetooth and I do not know where data is saved or if we can emulate flash cards, but is is a ready package - install and use - and it can connect to web => better than Kwyshell's); Android J2ME Runner: idem for App Runner (they are the same?). But I'll wait for more answers to see if there is a better solution...

Comment: ok, your answer does not solve all problems, but Mpowerplayer is good enough.

Comment: ach so! done :)